# Mailjet API ignore CC if cc email is null

Tags: mailjet

how to ignore "CC" if CC Email id null. Below is the code which i added in my C# application. If we have To and CC Email the mail triggers successfully without any issues. But if CC Email is null then mail triggers fails and response says email id null. I tried inserting if conditions but it didn't work.

```
MailjetClient client = new MailjetClient(APIKey, SecretKey)
                {
                    Version = ApiVersion.V3_1,
                };
                MailjetRequest request = new MailjetRequest
                {
                    Resource = Send.Resource,
                }
                .Property(Send.Messages, new JArray { new JObject {
                    {"From", new JObject { {"Email", EmailFrom }, { "Name", EmailFromName } } },
                    {"To", new JArray { new JObject { {"Email", Emaildetails.EmailTO } } } },
                    {"Cc", new JArray { new JObject { {"Email", Emaildetails.EmailCC } } } },
                    {"Subject", Emaildetails.EmailSubject},
                    {"HTMLPart", Emaildetails.EmailTemplate}
                 }
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a guess, but if `Emaildetails.EmailCC` is `null` then don't include

```cs
{"Cc", new JArray { new JObject { {"Email", Emaildetails.EmailCC } } } },
```

in your `JObject`.